# Converting Fortran Code to MATLAB using f2matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have tried to convert a Fortran code to MATLAB code using f2matlab but it gives me error of undeclared function or variable "optimize_wear_rate(dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, ap, tc, bt, varargin)
Undefined function or variable 'dl'.". This is the function where the problem lies.

```
function [dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, ap, tc, bt]=optimize_wear_rate(dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, ap, tc, bt,varargin)
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

persistent alpha_ml beta crit_df crit_f crit_rsqr d delalpha df error f g integral iter iter_nr loop maxiter rsqr rsqr_old ; 


pr_shape=size(pr);pr=reshape(pr,1,[]);
tr_shape=size(tr);tr=reshape(tr,1,[]);
sv_shape=size(sv);sv=reshape(sv,1,[]);
dw_shape=size(dw);dw=reshape(dw,1,[]);
 if isempty(integral), integral=0; end

 if isempty(maxiter), maxiter=1000; end
 if isempty(crit_rsqr), crit_rsqr=1.0d-08; end
 if isempty(crit_df), crit_df=1.0d-20; end
 if isempty(crit_f), crit_f=1.0d-20; end

 if isempty(d), d=zeros(1,3); end
 if isempty(g), g=zeros(1,3); end
 if isempty(error), error=0; end
 if isempty(beta), beta=0; end
 if isempty(rsqr_old), rsqr_old=0; end
 if isempty(rsqr), rsqr=0; end
 if isempty(alpha_ml), alpha_ml=0; end
 if isempty(f), f=0; end
 if isempty(df), df=0; end
 if isempty(delalpha), delalpha=0; end
 if isempty(iter), iter=0; end
 if isempty(loop), loop=0; end
 if isempty(iter_nr), iter_nr=0; end



ap=7.50d0;
tc=0.50d0;
bt=3.00d0;

d(1:3)=0.0d0;

beta    =0.0d0;
rsqr_old=1.0d0;

iter=0;
for loop=1: maxiter
[dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, ap, tc, bt, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, error]=error_vs(dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, ap, tc, bt, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, error);
%WRITE(*,'(I4, 7(1X,ES12.4))') ITER, SQRT(RSQR_OLD), SQRT(ERROR), AP, TC, BT

[dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, ap, tc, bt, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, g]=derror_vs(dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, ap, tc, bt, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, g);

rsqr=g(1).^2+g(2).^2+g(3).^2;
beta=0.0d0;
 if(loop>1) 
     beta=rsqr./rsqr_old;
if(sqrt(rsqr./3.0d0)<crit_rsqr)
 goto('100');
end
d(1:3)=g(1:3)+beta.*d(1:3);

%---NEWTON_RAPHSON ALGORITHM FOR 1-D SEARCH
alpha_ml=0.0d0;
for iter_nr=1: 1000
[dumvar1,dumvar2,dumvar3, dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, d, f ]=dalpha_error_vs(ap+alpha_ml.*d(1), tc+alpha_ml.*d(2), bt+alpha_ml.*d(3), dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, d, f );
[dumvar1,dumvar2,dumvar3, dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, d, df]=ddalpha_error_vs(ap+alpha_ml.*d(1), tc+alpha_ml.*d(2), bt+alpha_ml.*d(3), dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, d, df);
if(abs(df)<=crit_df || abs(f)<=crit_f)
  tempBreak=1;break;
end
delalpha=-(f./df);
alpha_ml=alpha_ml+delalpha;
end
if ~exist('tempBreak','var'), iter_nr= 1000+1; end; clear tempBreak
ap=ap+alpha_ml.*d(1);
tc=tc+alpha_ml.*d(2);
bt=bt+alpha_ml.*d(3);

rsqr_old=rsqr;

iter=fix(iter+1);
end
% LABEL 100
integral=ap.*((0.5d0.*(5.0d0.^2)-tc.*5.0d0)-(0.5d0.*(tc.^2)-tc.*tc) ).*(0.5d0.*(5.0d0.^2)+bt.*5.0d0);
%---> Final Output is [ gram/sec ]
[writeErrFlag]=writeFmt(1,['%4d',repmat(['%1x','%12.4e'] ,1,8)],'iter','sqrt(rsqr_old)','sqrt(error)','integral','ap','tc','bt');
%---> Changed to m^3/sec multiplied by [ 1E-03/Density ]
return;
end
if ~exist('tempBreak','var'), loop= maxiter+1;
end
clear tempBreak
end
```

Comment: Is f2matlab the reason why nearly all MATLAB code looks unreadable? 

Comment: yeah ... i fear yes

Comment: What happens if you replace all the stuff in the inside with just a single `return`?

Comment: haven't tried it ... wait !!1

Comment: @MateenUlhaq same error " optimize_wear_rate(dl, zp, kp, zs, ks, pr, tr, sv, dw, ndat, accel, distance, ap, tc, bt, varargin)
Undefined function or variable 'dl'. "